# Execute terminal commands in C++ with arguments passed from terminal with C++ file when executing it

Tags: c++, python-3.x, terminal

What would be the equivalent of the following Python code in C++?

```
import sys, os
#Example command
os.system(f"touch {sys.argv[1]}")
```

Comment: `fork` + `exec` or `system()` (but `system` has lots of issues and is best left unused).

Comment: you can use `system` like in python, of `popen`, these two functions are also C functions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a close equivalent can be :

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
  if (argc == 2)
  {
    std::string cmd = std::string("touch ") + argv[1];

    std::system(cmd.c_str());
  }
  else 
    std::cerr << "Usage: " << argv[0] << " <file>" << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

I preferred to check the number of args rather than to hope it is not just 1.

Anyway it is also possible to do that without using *touch* nor *system* or equivalent, your program creates the file if it does not exist, or to set its modification date&time to the current date&time